# Handle visibleif on text change in surveyjs

Tags: surveyjs

I am using SurveyJS to render questionnaire. I have two elements, one textbox and other dropdown. Until there is value in textbox I want to hide dropdown.

I am trying to use visibleIf to control this behaviour.

eg: I tried below

but none seems to work.

```
visibleIf: "{question1} != ''"
visibleIf: "{question1} != undefined"
visibleIf: "{question1} != null"
visibleIf: "{question1} != 'undefined'"
visibleIf: "{question1} != 'null'"
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Finally after going through documentations, I found that we can use 'notempty' operator for this operation.

Syntax: visibleIf: "{question1} notempty ''"